# Cannot redirect to other page after input the data, even though the data has been recorded in the database

Tags: php

```
<?php 

require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'USERNAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PASSWORD', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM regis WHERE USERNAME=:USERNAME OR EMAIL=:EMAIL";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    
    // bind parameter ke query
    $params = array(
        ":USERNAME" => $username,   
        ":EMAIL" => $username
    );

    $stmt->execute($params);

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // jika user terdaftar
    if($user){
        // verifikasi password
        if(password_verify($password, $user["PASSWORD"])){
            // buat Session
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
            // login sukses, alihkan ke halaman timeline
            header("Location: timeline.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the auth.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: Never modify passwords. As a matter of fact why do you filter `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` on the input values?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this .. If you want you can also add a link to the page in case the redirect fails .. :)

```
<?
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
        $url = 'login.php';
        header("Location: ". $url);
        ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title></title>
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<? echo $url;?>">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.location.href = '<? echo $url;?>';
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
            
                </body>
            </html>
        <?
    }
?>
```